# I wish to find sites within a distance of a route, using django GEOS filters, by converting a route to a polygon to test model instances within

Tags: postgis, postgresql, route, django

**Python**  2.7.12 (default, Jul 1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

**Django**  (1, 7, 11, 'final', 0)

**Postgres**    [u'PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit']

**Postgis** [u'POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797', u'GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084', u'PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015', u'GDAL="GDAL 2.1.1, released 2016/07/07', u'LIBXML="2.9.3', u'TOPOLOGY RASTER']

We have a mapping application that uses a crude mechanism to locate sites within a certain distance (20 kilometres) of a google derived route expressed at Lat and Longs.

I have a database of sites that I wish to display if they are within 20 kilometres of the route.

The previous mechanism took 1 in 20 way-points from the list and searched a sphere from that point adding any included sites into a set of points.
This is inefficient but dates back some three years and ran surprisingly well.

Upon upgrading to Postgres 9.5 the performance has taken a considerable hit and the mechanism is no longer practical.

I would like to generate a polygon or closed loop around the route, the nature of the end caps are unimportant, and then perform a contains or covers (when we get to Django 1.10) to extract the sites.

Is this a practical approach and if so how does one best perform the route to polygon transformation?

I am keen to not have to optimize in SQL as the application performs all it's operation using django filters.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? Yesterday marked it as correct, it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to accurately answer whether it's practical or not, you can get started on answering

> how does one best perform the route to polygon transformation

By checking out [PostGIS's ST_Buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html).  If your route is a collection of points you may have to use [ST_Collect](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Collect.html) in a subquery.

Comment: By using lineString to form the geometry from the points I didn't need to use ST_Collect.

 
Much thanks for the help. ST_Buffer is indeed my friend. 

In purest django . . . points from lat, lng points arrive in list near from 


    `from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry   
    from  django.contrib.gis.geos   import LineString  
  
    route_nodes = [(node['lat'], node['lng']) for node in near]   
    route_line = LineString(*route_nodes) route_buffer =  route_line.buffer(0.1) ~ 10km   
    sites = Site.objects.filter(site__location__intersects=route_buffer)`

Comment: I'm really sorry I can't get the formatting to work ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use function in database - it's propably best option when you care about performance. Since you didn't provide any data I made my own:

```
create table sites (
  id int,
  name text,
  geom geometry);

insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (1,'point1',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,1),4326));
insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (2,'point2',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2,2),4326));
insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (3,'point3',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(3,3),4326));
insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (4,'point4',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(4,4),4326));
insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (5,'point5',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(5,5),4326));
insert into sites(id,name,geom) values (6,'point6',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(6,6),4326));
```

If there is many records in sites table you may need some index:

```
create index sites_geom_idx on sites using gist(geom);
```

And now it's time for function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_sites(IN inp_waypoints text[][])
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, name text) AS
$BODY$
Declare g_waypoints geometry[];
  g_path_buffer geometry;   
BEGIN

--create geometries from lat lon

for i in 1 .. array_upper(inp_waypoints,1)
loop
g_waypoints[i] = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint((inp_waypoints[i][1])::int,(inp_waypoints[i][2])::int),4326);
end loop;

--create line + buffer

g_path_buffer = (ST_Buffer((ST_MakeLine(g_waypoints))::geography,20000))::geometry;

--select from table

return query select s.id, s.name from sites s where ST_Intersects(s.geom,g_path_buffer);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

You're using it like this:

```
select * from find_sites('{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}')
```

Comment: It works VERY nicely. Also the ability to order along the route AND extract distance from the original route seems to load the process hardly at all.


        sites = sitefilter.filter(
            fuelsite__location__intersects=route_buffer
        ).distance(route_line).order_by('fuelsite__location')

Comment: OK, so could you please mark it as correct and/or upvote? TNX